# how to make printable version of a webpage?

Tags: html, css, printing

I would like to make a printable version of my web page. I have already tried using CSS to make a separate stylesheet for the page but it is not working properly.(i.e. it will not get rid of  margin at the top also the menu bar background will not go away.) the page consists of hundreds of tables and when i do a print preview they also get split between pages sometimes.

these tables are generated dynamically according to users choices in checkboxes is it possible to add a printable link which will take the content from the current page and put it into a page where it can be mad more printer friendly?

Comment: Really, to have the most control over layout, you'll probably want to do something like generate a PDF.  This is considerably more work than creating a separate style sheet, however.

Comment: how would I go about doing that I have never tried it?

Comment: This would need to be done on the back-end.  So you would have to submit the user's choices to the back-end and then use most likely some pdf library to generate the pdf file.

Comment: have you tried the `@media print`? In that you can overwrite any styles you have in your default stylesheet

Comment: While not a complete answer, check out [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) as a good starting point.

Comment: @ZoltanToth +1 Creating a PDF is probably overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need of two different pages. You should create a different CSS sheet. After you copy the existing one, just set everything in black/white (or a few colours if you really need them), remove any menus and elements you don't need by putting `display: none;` in their CSS declaration, and to get rid of the unwanted margins. You should just put a `margin: 0` or `margin-top: 0` declaration here and there. If you don't show your HTML and CSS code is difficult to be more specific.

Comment: as I mentioned I have tried this but a few elements are not following the print css rules and still showing up any idea why?

Comment: You should analyze the code. They could still inherit the properties from some parent elements. Try to use something like Firebug or Safari/Chrome built-in code inspector. On the right you can see the CSS properties for the selected element and where it inherits them from. That could help you a lot.

Comment: Probably because they have more weight in your web CSS (i.e. in web stylesheet you have a rule for an `id` and in the print one you have it for a `class`). To fix that add `!important` to the rules in your print CSS

Answer (score 17):

You can make printer friendly version of your page with `@media print`

```
@media print {
        your styles here
}
```

For example in [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) they have the basic rules to which you can add anything of your own:

```
@media print {
    * { background: transparent !important; color: black !important; text-shadow: none !important; filter:none !important;
    -ms-filter: none !important; } /* Black prints faster: sanbeiji.com/archives/953 */
    p a, p a:visited { color: #444 !important; text-decoration: underline; }
    p a[href]:after { content: " (" attr(href) ")"; }
    abbr[title]:after { content: " (" attr(title) ")"; }
    .ir a:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after { content: ""; }  /* Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links */
    pre, blockquote { border: 1px solid #999; page-break-inside: avoid; }
    thead { display: table-header-group; } /* css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Printing_Tables */
    tr, img { page-break-inside: avoid; }
    @page { margin: 0.5cm; }
    p, h2, h3 { orphans: 3; widows: 3; }
    h2, h3{ page-break-after: avoid; }
    .hide-on-print { display: none !important; }
    .print-only { display: block !important; }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use CSS with [`@media` rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530813%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Define your styles for displaying on the screen with `@media screen` and `@media print` for print-view.  Control page breaks with [`page-break-*` attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358813%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
@media screen {
    body {
        background-image: url(/images/background.png);
    }
}
@media print {
    body {
        background-image: none;
    }
    tr {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to make another stylesheet for the print version and add the attribute `media="print"` to the `<link/>` for it.