# Printing a large table on multiple pages

Tags: php, html, css, printing, html-table

I have a PHP output, creating an HTML table (size XL) and I would like to have a `print` button on my page which automatically makes sure the table is printed out using the correct sizes etc.

For example I would like my table to be printed out horizontally and the table headers on every page, without all of the PHP buttons and parameters aside of the table.

Is there an efficient way to do this without having to rewrite the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to accurately and consistently provide a print layout in html (especially across multiple pages), as different browsers will render your page differently.  If you want to be 100% certain how a page will be printed, one way to deal with this would be to render to a PDF.

[PrinceXML](http://princexml.com/) is a very good way to convert HTML output into PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best answer to this is to dynamically insert a "Print" CSS style sheet for when a print GET parameter is provided. That way you can hide all of your HTML elements from the printed document without a massive overhaul of code.

A similar question was asked and answered here:
[how to make printable version of a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994403/how-to-make-printable-version-of-a-webpage)

Hope it helps.