# Provide a pdf, if the website should be printed

Tags: html, pdf, printing

Is there a way to deposit a pdf in my Website, that should be used, if somebody tries to print the site? I hope you guys understand me despite my bad english.

Comment: The same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994403/how-to-make-printable-version-of-a-webpage

Comment: Well thats not really the same Question. All Answers circle around using @media print, i want to know, if i can just have a pdf at the Ready, which will then Always be printed.

Comment: You can add a print button maybe ? with your own pdf provided

Comment: I could do that, but i guess the most People will just go STRG+p to print.